# What's the point of the character code?

Tags: starcraft-2

Whats the point of having to put in both the character name and the character code of the user your trying add as a friend?

I don't really understand their thinking, it just sends a request anyways doesn't it?

I can see how it would cut down on spam requests, (those people that try to add everyone they play with as a friend) but it just seems inconvenient.  And now I wonder if its a bad thing just posting character code with my character name for people to add me.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The character code is to allow for anyone to have *whatever* name they want. Two people can both be "Walter", for instance, with one being "Walter.414" and the other being "Walter.811".

It's there so people can pick the name they want, and have it be available, no matter what.

Comment: oh.. that now makes total sense.

Answer (score 2):

Generally multiple input for locating a character is due to people being able to have the same input of one field. Such as someone being able to have the same name.

The Character code is there because the character code plus the name make a unique identifier. No two people have the same name and the same character code. This allows them to not have to put restrictions on naming, and simply requiring that everyone has a character code.